# How to get information of cluster nodes with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing

Is there a way to get a cluster information and it's nodes and find which one is the active node and passive node, in case of a Active-Passive cluster? I was looking into Get-ClusterNode command that is explained in the Microsoft documentation. I was wondering if I do this command:

```
Get-ClusterNode -Cluster cluster1
```

and the output is:

```
 Name           ID    State 
 ----           --    ----- 
 node1           1     Up 
 node2           2     Up
```

I was wondering if the property State defines if 'up' means active and 'down' means passive. I'm not sure if this returns the information that I need. Can anyone confirm or deny if this method returns what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want to look at which nodes own the resources and/or groups.

```
Get-Cluster <ClusterManagementName> | Get-ClusterGroup | Format-Table Name,OwnerNode

Get-Cluster <ClusterManagementName> | Get-ClusterResource | Format-Table Cluster,Name,RecourceType,OwnerGroup,OwnerNode
```

Comment: and the OwnerNode is the active node?

Comment: Yes it should be.